# How to solve Gauss seidel power flow solution using matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

Hi I am trying to make program for a Gauss seidel power flow solution using matlab and i am facing an error in line 55.
"Error in ==> gauss at 55
[ybus,ych]=ybus;"
How to solve this error? I already tried by adding the function "ybus" but still this error is occurring

```
  % Function ybus
    % THIS IS THE PROGRAM FOR CREATING Ybus MATRIX.

    function [yb,ych]=ybus

     % The line impedances are

     zz=[0 0.02+0.1i 0 0 0.05+0.25i
        0.02+0.1i 0 0.04+0.2i 0 0.05+0.25i
        0 0.04+0.2i 0 0.05+0.25i 0.08+0.4i
        0 0 0.05+0.25i 0 0.1+0.5i
        0.05+0.25i 0.05+0.25i 0.08+0.4i 0.1+0.5i 0];

     % The line chargings are

     ych=j*[0 0.03 0 0 0.02
        0.03 0 0.025 0 0.020
        0 0.025 0 0.02 0.01
        0  0 0.02 0 0.075
        0.02 0.02 0.01 0.075 0];


      % The Ybus matrix is formed here

      for m=1:5
         for n=1:5
            if zz(m,n) == 0
               yb(m,n)=0;
            else
               yb(m,n)=-1/zz(m,n);
            end
         end
      end

      for m=1:5
         ysum=0;
         csum=0;
         for n=1:5
          ysum=ysum+yb(m,n);
          csum=csum+ych(m,n);
       end
       yb(m,m)=csum-ysum;
    end


    % Program loadflow_gs
    % THIS IS A GAUSS-SEIDEL POWER FLOW PROGRAM

    clear all

    d2r=pi/180;w=100*pi;

    % The Y_bus matrix is

    [ybus,ych]=ybus;

    g=real(ybus);b=imag(ybus);

    % The given parameters and initial conditions are

    p=[0;-0.96;-0.35;-0.16;0.24];
    q=[0;-0.62;-0.14;-0.08;-0.35];
    mv=[1.05;1;1;1;1.02];
    th=[0;0;0;0;0];
    v=[mv(1);mv(2);mv(3);mv(4);mv(5)];

    acc=input('Enter the acceleration constant: ');
    del=1;indx=0;

    % The Gauss-Seidel iterations starts here

    while del>1e-6

    % P-Q buses  

       for i=2:4

         tmp1=(p(i)-j*q(i))/conj(v(i));
         tmp2=0;
         for k=1:5
            if (i==k)
               tmp2=tmp2+0;
            else
               tmp2=tmp2+ybus(i,k)*v(k);
            end
         end     

         vt=(tmp1-tmp2)/ybus(i,i);
         v(i)=v(i)+acc*(vt-v(i));

     end

    % P-V bus

         q5=0;
         for i=1:5
            q5=q5+ybus(5,i)*v(i);
         end
         q5=-imag(conj(v(5))*q5);
         tmp1=(p(5)-j*q5)/conj(v(5));
         tmp2=0;
         for k=1:4
            tmp2=tmp2+ybus(5,k)*v(k);
         end

         vt=(tmp1-tmp2)/ybus(5,5);
         v(5)=abs(v(5))*vt/abs(vt);

      % Calculate P and Q

         for i=1:5
            sm=0;
            for k=1:5
               sm=sm+ybus(i,k)*v(k);
            end
            s(i)=conj(v(i))*sm;
         end

      % The mismatch

         delp=p-real(s)';
         delq=q+imag(s)';

         delpq=[delp(2:5);delq(2:4)];
         del=max(abs(delpq));
         indx=indx+1;
         if indx==1
            pause
         end

     end

     'GS LOAD FLOW CONVERGES IN ITERATIONS',indx,pause
     'FINAL VOLTAGE MAGNITUDES ARE',abs(v)',pause

     'FINAL ANGLES IN DEGREE ARE',angle(v)'/d2r,pause
    'THE REAL POWERS IN EACH BUS IN MW ARE',(real(s)+[0 0 0 0 0.24])*100,pause  

    'THE REACTIVE POWERS IN EACH BUS IN MVar ARE',(-imag(s)+[0 0 0 0 0.11])*10
```

Comment: The error is...what?

Comment: "Error in ==> gauss at 55
[ybus,ych]=ybus;" this is shown as error

Comment: There should be more in the error line, describing what the error is...

Comment: description of error is not given

Comment: this is now showing with the error  "Undefined function or variable ybus Error in ==> gauss at 55
[ybus,ych]=ybus; ".

Comment: Output variables cannot be equal to function name. Change `[ybus,ych]=ybus` to `[yb, ych] = ybus` or similar.

Comment: `Reference to a cleared variable ybus.` I got this error with your code.

Comment: 1) Line 49: Why using `clear` in a function? 2) Grammatically, `ybus` is the function name, not a variable. In Line 55 you are assigning a function name to some variable, which is not allowed, and doesn't work for your purpose either. 3) `ybus` is not existing at Line 55.